# Remove Quotes from large text file/data.table

Tags: r, data.table, gsub, large-files

I have a large text file with 57 columns and ~3 million rows 1.2 GB on which I want to remove the quotes (either double or single)  from the cell values e.g..

Column1 Column2

"1" "2" ...

"3" "4" ...

... ...

Currently there are 2 implementations.

Implementation No 1 - **WORKING**:

Read the file using the readLines base function

```
system.time(example1 <- gsub("\"", "", readLines("large-file.txt"), perl = TRUE))

user  system elapsed 

88.756   1.172  90.226
```

Implementation No 2 - **NOT WORKING**:

Read the file with **fread** function from the **data.table package** and then unquote with gsub.

```
library(data.table)

system.time(example2 <- fread("Dropbox/Review/case studies/evidence.txt"))

user  system elapsed 

38.052   6.176  59.764

example2 <- gsub("\"", "", example2)
```

Which usually leaves my 4GB laptop either dead or after more that 10 minutes I kill the rsession.

I have also tried different solutions using the data.table but without success.

e.g.

```
example3 <- data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x %like% "\"")]
```

In order to at least mark the faulty cells.

How can I combine the fread reading speed with fast gsub-ing in a data.table?

Comment: How about `df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert)`, where `df` is the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delete quotes outside R (eg, using `tr` with option `-d`).

Use `fread` to read output from `tr` with `-d` option:

```
data.table::fread("tr -d \'\"\' < INPUT.txt")
```

Comment: Great! Tr did the job! I did not know about the tr command neither about the fact that you can feed fread with a linux command. However this hack would work only on a linux enviroment, so academically speaking, is there an alternative for Windows?

Comment: @VangelisTheodorakis If it's super large file I would stick to `tr` (ignoring windows problem :-)). One simple option is to use `fread` and `gsub`, but read and modify file in chunks. PS., it's not only linux, but Mac too :-)

Comment: Yes I thought about reading in chunks, but this would also add some overhead computationally speaking so it was a last resort idea. Actually the thing that I do not understand is why the readLines was faster? Was is because it returns a serialized object (character) and not an heavy object such as the data.table (which is essetialy a list)?